# Solr GermanNormalizationFilter and special chars

Tags: solr, solr5

We use Solr 5.4 and have some text fields defined as `text_de` with following schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

which is default configuration. I wonder why a search for `name:Rosewein` has no results, but `name:Roséwein` returns related entries.
So I tried to query field `name` with some special chars and enabled option `debugQuery` which results in:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "debugQuery": "true",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "name:ÁÀÂÄÃåĀĂÆæöüßéèêíóú",
      "_": "1459935371889",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "name:ÁÀÂÄÃåĀĂÆæöüßéèêíóú",
    "querystring": "name:ÁÀÂÄÃåĀĂÆæöüßéèêíóú",
    "parsedquery": "name:aaaaãåāăææousséèêiou",
    "parsedquery_toString": "name:aaaaãåāăææousséèêiou",
    "explain": {},
    "QParser": "LuceneQParser",
...
```

have a look at field `parsedquery` which shows, that not all variants are replaced with ASCII representation. I cannot use `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` as filter, because then german umlauts can get lost, because in some cases they are converted from `ü` to `ue` and so on.

But what I can't understand: why are `íóúá` converted to `ioua` but not `é` which is kept as `é`?

And: is there a way to convert all these special vocals to their ASCII representation, but allow to be umlauts converted to `ae Ae ue Ue` and so on? (Without having to recompile Solr)

Comment: can you try German2 with SnowballPorterFilterFactory...?

Comment: As one can read here https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/analyzers-common/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanNormalizationFilter.html souldn't Solr use German2 already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for custom character mapping rules, you can use [MappingCharFilterFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#MappingCharFilterFactory), which takes a config file with the rules. [Techproducts example schema](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/5.5.0/solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/managed-schema#L597) showcases it (commented out, so drops out after first modification). Check [mapping-FoldToASCII.txt](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/5.5.0/solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/mapping-FoldToASCII.txt) and [mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/5.5.0/solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt)